# Is there a way to catch the "Search Unavailable" exception that is thrown when doing a SOSL query?

Tags: apex, exception, sosl, search

We have a **try/catch** block around the line doing the query, but we still get this exception mailed to us on some **SOSL** queries:

```
List<List<SObject>> ret, queryResult;
try {         
     queryResult = search.query('FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + 
     '\' IN ' + searchFields + ' RETURNING ' + returningClause);       
} catch (Exception e) {         
     return null;       
}
```

caused by:

> System.UnexpectedException: Search unavailable

Is there a way to catch this Exception and retry, or handle it more gracefully?

Comment: What exception type are you catching in your catch? What code is calling this query when this exception is raised? Are you attempting to use SOSL on an object that does not support it? Some more details and code examples might help here.

Comment: `List<List<SObject>> ret, queryResult;  
    try {  
      queryResult = search.query('FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '\' IN ' + searchFields + ' RETURNING ' + returningClause);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
      return null;  
    }  `

Comment: In this case, we are searching Lead, Contact, or Account objects and the searchfields and returning clause are constants that list the fields we want.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are three types of exceptions that you cannot catch: UnknownException, UnexpectedException, and LimitException. The first two are situations that your code can't handle, since they are system problems, and the latter you're not allowed to handle.

I'd recommend reporting this exception to support, since your query shouldn't be failing this way. Only QueryException should be possible in normal situations.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue today due to the Salesforce performance degradation issue and it is got resolved automatically once the servers are up and running. As @sfdcfox said It would be better to contact the support if any org is facing this issue frequently or for long periods. Below is the message from https://status.salesforce.com/

> There’s a Salesforce service performance degradation. Users can access the Salesforce service, but some functionality can be unavailable or running at less than optimal performance. General and intermittent slow performance, timeouts, and connectivity issues are possible. We’re investigating the issue and an update will be provided in 30 minutes or sooner if we have more information.

[image: Screenshot of the Issue]